# Throttle Upload in Local Env

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

Is there a way to slow down the upload so progress bars can be tested in local development? Uploading is just too fast and it turns immediate into being done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Chrome's Inspector has a throttling option: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/network-conditions?hl=en